# Questions about Seth Lloyd's Programming the Universe?

Tags: computability, quantum-computing, physics

I have been interested in Seth Lloyd's cosmological model (which proposes that the universe is a computer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_the_Universe, https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0501135) since long ago. While I was "researching" about this topic, I found an interesting article that hungarian author Zoltán Galántai wrote (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1501.01754.pdf)

I was wondering if you would answer a few questions I have about the article. It would be very helpful if any of you could find some time to answer them.

1. In Zoltán's article he built a table indicating the possible types of computation that could exist. In the type "C3", he says:
   "Computing based on different constants - in some cases it is impossible to interpret Lloyd's equations for them"
   What does he exactly mean with this? Would Lloyd's cosmological model be compatible with this? Would his model be applicable to a universe with this type of computation?
2. He also built a table indicating the possible types of computational universes based on the speed of light. In the type 3 (U3) he says that computation is impossible since the speed of light would be 0. But, if that universe had some structure similar to a wormhole or any other kind of instant communication (maybe some kind of teleportation system or some kind of quantum entanglement that would be superluminal), couldn't light be able to transmit information without the need of moving at all? Couldn't that allow computation to occur? Anyways, could Lloyd's model be applied to a static (c=0) universe? I mean, would that model be able to "produce" that type of universe?